# Encounter "unexpected end of block data" when try to ignore the serialVersionUID of the serialized object(A List of Object)

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization, objectinputstream, serialversionuid

We have serialized a list of object(Say ReportSetting) and persist as byte array field into database. But we haven't declared the *serialVersionUID* in the class before and after the class has been changed by adding some more fields, we got the below exception obviously.

```
java.io.InvalidClassException: test.ReportSetting; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 4360738426892236309, local class serialVersionUID = 5814220747992558303
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:621)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1623)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1518)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1774)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
    at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(ArrayList.java:791)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1896)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
    at test.SerializationUtil.deserializeObject(SerializationUtil.java:50)
```

We have tried the below code for redefine the **class descriptor** of ObjectInputStream(Credits to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816559/make-java-runtime-ignore-serialversionuids)), for avoiding the serialVersionUID check when deserializing the object.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InvalidClassException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectStreamClass;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;


public class DecompressibleInputStream extends ObjectInputStream {

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DecompressibleInputStream.class);

    public DecompressibleInputStream(InputStream in) throws IOException {
        super(in);
    }

    protected ObjectStreamClass readClassDescriptor() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        ObjectStreamClass resultClassDescriptor = super.readClassDescriptor(); // initially streams descriptor
        Class localClass; // the class in the local JVM that this descriptor represents.
        try {
            localClass = Class.forName(resultClassDescriptor.getName()); 
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            logger.error("No local class for " + resultClassDescriptor.getName(), e);
            return resultClassDescriptor;
        }
        ObjectStreamClass localClassDescriptor = ObjectStreamClass.lookup(localClass);
        if (localClassDescriptor != null) { // only if class implements serializable
            final long localSUID = localClassDescriptor.getSerialVersionUID();
            final long streamSUID = resultClassDescriptor.getSerialVersionUID();
            if (streamSUID != localSUID) { // check for serialVersionUID mismatch.
                final StringBuffer s = new StringBuffer("Overriding serialized class version mismatch: ");
                s.append("local serialVersionUID = ").append(localSUID);
                s.append(" stream serialVersionUID = ").append(streamSUID);
                Exception e = new InvalidClassException(s.toString());
                logger.error("Potentially Fatal Deserialization Operation.", e);
                resultClassDescriptor = localClassDescriptor; // Use local class descriptor for deserialization
            }
        }
        return resultClassDescriptor;
    }
}
```

The Test Unit code as below:

```
@Test
public void getReportSettings() throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException
{
    Device device;
    device = deviceDao.findOne("ABC");
    System.out.println(device);
    List<ReportSetting> reportSetting = (List<ReportSetting>) SerializationUtil.deserializeObjectByLocalClassDescriptor(device.getReportSetting());
}

public static Object deserializeObjectByLocalClassDescriptor(byte[] serializedData) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
{
        if (serializedData == null) return null;
        Object object = null;
        try (DecompressibleInputStream objectInputStream = new DecompressibleInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(serializedData)))
        {
            object = objectInputStream.readObject();
        }
        return object;
}
```

And we got the below exception:

```
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: unexpected end of block data
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1373)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
    at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(ArrayList.java:791)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1896)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
    at test.SerializationUtil.deserializeObjectByLocalClassDescriptor(SerializationUtil.java:61)
    at test.TestDatabaseServiceImpl.getReportSettings(TestDatabaseServiceImpl.java:30)
```

The **ReportSetting** class is now looks like as below, the isHistorical field and its getter and setter are being added later as *serialVersionUID* 5814220747992558303.

```
public class ReportSetting implements Serializable
{
    private static final long   serialVersionUID    = 5814220747992558303L;
    private String  name;
    private Boolean isReport;
    private Boolean isHistorical;

    public ReportSetting()
    {}

    public ReportSetting(String nodeName, Boolean isReport, Boolean isHistorical)
    {
        this.name = nodeName;
        this.isReport = isReport;
        this.isHistorical = isHistorical;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Boolean getIsReport()
    {
        return this.isReport;
    }

    public void setIsReport(Boolean isReport)
    {
        this.isReport = isReport;
    }

    public Boolean getIsHistorical()
    {
        return this.isHistorical;
    }

    public void setIsHistorical(Boolean isHistorical)
    {
        this.isHistorical = isHistorical;
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Why did you change the `serialVersionUID` in the first place? That's the real problem.

Comment: Hi EJP, sorry, I didn't get it. You mean why I changed the value of the serialVersionUID field of ReportSetting class? In the first beginning, the ReportSetting class didn't declare serialVersionUID field, and after modifying, its serialVersionUID changed to 5814220747992558303

Comment: Why? Don't do that. Set it to the value reported by the `serialver` tool when run on the original .class file. Don't mess around with this field, or the kind of bandaid code above that attempts to paper over this mistake.